# Apply multiple filters with Autofilter

Tags: vba, autofilter

company is an array containing unknown number of companies;

```
For i = 1 To 50
Worksheets("Data_Claims").Activate
Range("A1").AutoFilter _
Field:=1, _
Criteria1:=company(i)
If IsEmpty(company(i)) = True Then
Exit For
Next i
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the value within `company`, try this:

```
Worksheets("Data_Claims").Activate
Range("A1").AutoFilter _
Field:=1, _
Criteria1:=Array(company), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

no need to use loop here

Comment: No need `Array(company)` because `company` itself an array: `Worksheets("Data_Claims").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=company, Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: @711 No problem! Would you mind selecting my answer if it helps you : ) ?